# MVC ninject ViewEngine

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject

I am trying to create my own custom ViewEngine in MVC4 in order to do this I would like to inject a repository using ninject.

After reading several posts on stackoverflow and various blogs I came up with the code below:

**NewViewEngine.cs**

```
public class NewViewEngine: RazorViewEngine
{
    [Inject]
    private static IThemeRepository mThemeRepository { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

**NinjectControllerFactory**

```
public class NinjectControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    private IKernel ninjectKernel;

    public NinjectControllerFactory()
    {
        ninjectKernel = new StandardKernel(new NinjectSettings { UseReflectionBasedInjection = true });
        AddBindings();
    }

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        return controllerType == null ? null : (IController)ninjectKernel.Get(controllerType);
    }

    private void AddBindings()
    {
        ninjectKernel.Bind<IThemeRepository>().To<EFThemeRepository>();
    }
}
```

**Global.asax**

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new NinjectControllerFactory());

        ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
        ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new ThemeViewEngine("web"));
    }
```

However when I try to run this I get the following error:

*Object reference not set to an instance of an object* for mThemeRepository

so it would appear that my repository is in fact not getting injected and now I'm rather stumped, any ideas what the problem could be?

Comment: Are you sure you want to inject into a static property?

Comment: Private also wont work (search for ninject private and ninject static and you should find a question that covers this this territory adequate

Comment: You are right, I don't want it to be a static property, but IViewEngine is a static interface right? I've had a search for ninject private/static but I've not been able to find anything useful/ not really understood how it is relevant?

Comment: I modified the code within the class to the following : 
    [Inject]
    public IThemeRepository mThemeRepository { get; set; }
, however it still doesn't seem to inject?